# reset running count based on 1's and 0's of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
 {"categ": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 "value":  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 "Run_count":  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 6],
 "currentResults":  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6],
 "desiredResults":  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 })

data['Run_count'] = data['value'].where(data['value'].eq(1)).dropna().groupby(data['value'].where(data['value'].eq(1)).isna().cumsum()).ngroup()+1
data['currentResults'] = np.where(data['categ']==1,data['Run_count'].bfill(),0)
```

I am able to accomplish most of what I am trying to do aka what is in **data['currentResults']**

what I am trying to accomplish is at **id=15 where df['categ'] == 1**, I would like to restart the count again in **data['desiredCount']**.  Since df['categ'][13:14], they have the value of 0.  Currently at id = 15, ****data['currentResults']**** continues the count at "5", where I **want to restart/reset the count at 1**

I was thinking the easiest way to do accomplish might be to reset/restart the counter in the **"Run_count"** column based on my current code.

attached is an image below of what i'm trying to accomlish in **"desiredResults"**

[image]

Comment: Your question could be improved and clarified with a complete minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can set up boolean Series, then perform a custom [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
m1 = data['value'].ne(1)
m2 = data['categ'].ne(1)

data['out'] = (m1[~m2]
               .groupby(m2.cumsum())
               # increment 1 for each non-1 following a 1
               .transform(lambda g: (g&~g.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum()
               # add 1 if group starts with non-1 
                                    +(1-g.iloc[0]))
               .reindex(data.index, fill_value=0) # 0 if categ is non-1
              )
```

Output:

```
    categ  value  out
0       0      0    0
1       1      1    1
2       1      1    1
3       1      0    2
4       1      0    2
5       1      1    2
6       1      0    3
7       1      1    3
8       1      0    4
9       1      0    4
10      1      0    4
11      1      1    4
12      1      1    4
13      0      0    0
14      0      0    0
15      1      0    1
16      1      0    1
17      1      1    1
18      1      1    1
19      1      0    2
20      1      0    2
21      1      1    2
```

Intermediates:

```
    categ  value     m1     m2  m2.cumsum() g&~g_shift  out
0       0      0   True   True            1        NaN    0
1       1      1  False  False            1      False    1
2       1      1  False  False            1      False    1
3       1      0   True  False            1       True    2
4       1      0   True  False            1      False    2
5       1      1  False  False            1      False    2
6       1      0   True  False            1       True    3
7       1      1  False  False            1      False    3
8       1      0   True  False            1       True    4
9       1      0   True  False            1      False    4
10      1      0   True  False            1      False    4
11      1      1  False  False            1      False    4
12      1      1  False  False            1      False    4
13      0      0   True   True            2        NaN    0
14      0      0   True   True            3        NaN    0
15      1      0   True  False            3       True    1
16      1      0   True  False            3      False    1
17      1      1  False  False            3      False    1
18      1      1  False  False            3      False    1
19      1      0   True  False            3       True    2
20      1      0   True  False            3      False    2
21      1      1  False  False            3      False    2
```

---

##### updated question

For your updated question, it looks like you could just change the `m1` condition and remove the `+(1-g.iloc[0]))` correction factor:

```
m1 = data['value'].eq(1)
m2 = data['categ'].ne(1)

data['out'] = (m1[~m2]
               .groupby(m2.cumsum())
               # increment 1 for each non-1 following a 1
               .transform(lambda g: (g&~g.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum())
               .reindex(data.index, fill_value=0) # 0 if categ is non-1
              )
```

Output:

```
    categ  value  desiredResults  out
0       0      0               0    0
1       1      1               1    1
2       1      1               1    1
3       1      0               1    1
4       1      0               1    1
5       1      1               2    2
6       1      0               2    2
7       1      1               3    3
8       1      0               3    3
9       1      0               3    3
10      1      0               3    3
11      1      1               4    4
12      1      1               4    4
13      0      0               0    0
14      0      0               0    0
15      1      0               0    0
16      1      0               0    0
17      1      1               1    1
18      1      1               1    1
19      1      0               2    1  # this is however different!
20      1      0               2    1
21      1      1               2    2
```

Comment: thank you very much mozway,

we are almost there with your solution.  from ID[15:21], the count should start at ID = 17. aka  in column "out" the 1 should start counting on ID = 17 instead of ID = 15.  I am still trying to understand your code as I'm not that familiar w/ transform() and reIndex().   But I have this weird hunch that reIndex() needs to be adjusted to make that happen.

Comment: @aaaahhhhhh then the logic is unclear, why in `desiredResults` do you increment the number between rows 18 and 19 but not between 2 and 3? Which one is the correct logic? See updated answer.

Comment: mozway,  apologies on my end, for not being clear enough, realized I didn't do a good enough job explaining my logic of what i wanted to accomplish.  but your updated solution is the correct solution I was looking for.  1st condtion: if categ ==1, then we wnat to increment/increase desired result based on the range of 1's in categ. if categ ==0, we then want to reset our incrment/count in desired result.  2nd condition: within the range of 1's, we will increment "desiredResults as long as we don't have a successive strem of 1's.

Comment: so for example in value[1:2] we have a succesive row of 1's, we would then increment desiredResult +1.  And for value[5] and value[7] since the 1's are buy themselves, we would incrlement +1 twice since then don't have a successive row of 1's

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that iterates over the pairs of values in the 'categ' and 'value' series.

```
run_count = 0  # Keep track of current runing count
results = []   # Track run count for each pair of values

# Track previous pair to compare duplicate pairs
[prev_categ, prev_value] = [None, None]

# Iterate over each pair in series
for categ,value in data[['categ','value']].values:
    
    # Reset count
    if [categ,value]==[0,0]:
        run_count = 0
        
    # Increase count (only if first instance of pair)
    if ([categ,value]==[1,1]) & ([categ,value]!=[prev_categ, prev_value]):
        run_count=run_count+1
    
    results.append(run_count)
    
    # Previous pair is the current pair (before we reset)
    [prev_categ, prev_value] = [categ, value]
```

```
data['run_count'] = results
data
```

Output

```
    categ   value   run_count
0   0       0       0
1   1       1       1
2   1       1       1
3   1       0       1
4   1       0       1
5   1       1       2
6   1       0       2
7   1       1       3
8   1       0       3
9   1       0       3
10  1       0       3
11  1       1       4
12  1       1       4
13  0       0       0
14  0       0       0
15  1       0       0
16  1       0       0
17  1       1       1
18  1       1       1
19  1       0       1
20  1       0       1
21  1       1       2
```